# SearchView enlarges on focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

The problem i'm facing is, that when the SearchView gets the focus, the parent ActionBar enlarges nearly to the top of the keyboard (like in the screenshot below). The effect only occures if  both, the `android:fitsSystemWindow` attribute of the Toolbar and the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` style property are set to true. If one of them is false, the problem doesn't exist anymore.

What am i doin wrong? Did i miss any configuration?

I have the following simple layout in my activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/search_result_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The menu_main.xml looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search_button"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>

</menu>
```

Screenshot of the 'bug':
[image: Screenshot of the 'bug']

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to limit the toolbar's height like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

? Instead of using `wrap_content`?

(`?attr/actionBarSize` causes the system to choose the standard toolbar height for the current configuration, e.g. 56dp for portrait on mobile phone)